# How do you retrieve highest/last value of property out of collection of POCO objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using the example object below...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Worker
    {
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I get the highest/last value that is inside `List<Worker>` of `WorkerId` property?

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ:

```
var max = list.Max(x=>x.WorkerId);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var list = new List<Worker>();
int max = list.Max(m => m.WorkerId);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with constructor inside Worker?

Comment: @liger86, not really because the extension method operates against the list.